# Who is this fellow?

Tags: trees, insects

I just discovered a fellow running on the guava tree. I was wondering what this insect is and its functions?

I have attached the image and I currently live in India.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like *[Umbonia crassicornis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbonia_crassicornis)* collectively known as *thorn bugs* defense mechanism to fool their predators as thorn. Not sure about it's functions in garden, but I remember playing with them by dropping them on their head and looking at them struggle to come back on their legs, when I was a kid.